# .htaccess url-rewriting for hiding directory

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I want to know, what to write in my .htacess file for rewriting my urls.

I want :
* folder pointed : exemple.com/subfolder
* And the visible url : exemple.com/

Corrections:

I have my domain exemple.com pointing to public_html directory. My website is on exemple.com/subfolder. I want to go to the url exemple.com, I want it to show the content of exemple.com/subfolder but with exemple.com shown as url

Thank you

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Not really tried. I don't knw how to use the .htaccess very well